# Vuetify Flex Layout - is not filling the height

Tags: vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I have tried loads of different options with the following code, however, I can't get this to fill the remaining height. (The second layout should fill the remaining height) what am I doing wrong here?

```
<template>
  <div class="earnIndex">
    <v-container fluid fill-height>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex
          v-for="(offer, index) in offers"
          :key="index"
          xs2
          class="pa-1"
        >
          <SiteButton
            :site-name="offer.siteName"
          />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
      <v-layout column fill-height>
        <v-flex grow>
          <v-card>
            <p>
              test
            </p>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>
```

EDIT:

So here is my new code:

```
<template>
  <v-layout column wrap>
    <v-flex>
      <v-layout row wrap class="red">
        <v-flex
          v-for="(offer, index) in offers"
          :key="index"
          class="pa-1"
          xs2
        >
          <SiteButton
            :site-name="offer.siteName"
          />
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
    <v-flex grow align-content-start>
      <v-card height="100%">
        <p>
          test
        </p>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>
```

This creates the following:
[image]

I would like the card with "test" to start straight after the links at the top, and then fill the rest of the height.

Thank you in advanced for your help!

Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 1):

Try using `column fill-height` on the right side, and then `grow` on the `v-flex`...

```
<v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex v-for="(offer, index) in offers" :key="index" xs2 class="pa-1">
            <v-btn>{{ offer.siteName }}</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout column fill-height>
        <v-flex grow>
            <v-card class="fill-height">
                <p> test </p>
            </v-card>
        </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

https://codeply.com/p/bwE5ifP4Pe

Comment: Thanks, however, the first v-layout should be on top of the second one - this has them at either side.

Comment: The code you provided is a side-by-side layout. Can you provide the complete code including parent element(s)?

Comment: Sure, but thats pretty much all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need as much markup in your scenario and can cut this down to just a few lines.
I just filled in some numbers instead of your custom component in the v-for.
This will stretch the lower card to the maximum amount right after your for loop. The `v-row` and `v-col` is the way to go now in 2.0 (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/).

```
<div class="d-flex fill-height" style="flex-direction:column">
  <v-row class="blue">
    <v-col cols="2" v-for="i in 15" :key="i" class="pa-1">
      <v-btn>{{ i }}</v-btn>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
  <div class="fill-height" style="background-color: salmon">Down</div>
</div>
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-ox8x2)